# I want to update my data of my database in VB.net but I get Error Syntax

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

This is my problem:

When I click update button, I don't know how to fix this error:

My Error Message is:

> "Error: syntax error in union query"

This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    TestConnection()
    Try
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "(UPDATE tblUsers SET Username = '" & txtUserName.Text & "', Password = '" & txtUserPassword.Text &
                "', Usertype = '" & cbousertype.Text & "', WHERE UserID = '" & txtUserID.Text & "');"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, Conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Is it wrong?

[image: This is my Error message]

[image: This is My code]

Comment: While I dont see use of `UNION` in your query, you have an extra comma before `WHERE`. Remove that and try again.

Comment: i have deleted it but it still Error @shahkalpesh

Comment: Is it the same error (`union`)? If not, repost the error that you are seeing. What button did you click? Have you posted the code of the same button?

Comment: i got the same error message. i click on my Update button. Yeah code that i posted is the code at the update button click @shahkalpesh

Comment: Put breakpoints on `msgbox("Error` in all your code and run the code by clicking Update button. I dont know where the error is coming from unless the breakpoint gets hit which may not be from the `btnUpdate_Click`.

Comment: Do you have any coma in any of your input? You should look at using parameters. Print out your "sql" variable, it will help you see the problem.

Comment: i did it but how can i told u about it?(i am beginner sorry)@shahkalpesh

Comment: I dont know how to use parameters in it Could you show me about it?@the_lotus

Comment: Type in `msgbox(sql)` before `cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, Conn)`. Run the code and paste what sql gets displayed in the msgbox here for one to see if this is the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you two of you for try to help me and now my code work correctly, i still don't know what wrong but now i use parameters that you told me and now it work thank you very much :)

Comment: `Password` and `Username` should be reserved, wrap them in brackets, `[Password]` for example... you also IMHO should be disposing your objects when done, wrap them in `Using` statements...

Comment: @SeuMinh You can post the answer yourself and then "Accept" it. This is preferred to updating the title of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Now my problem has been solved thank you very much
i changed my code to use a parameters and then it work 
Now my code is :

```
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click 

    TestConnection()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "UPDATE tblUsers SET Username=?, [Password]=?, Usertype=? where UserID=?"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, Conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtUserName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtUserPassword.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cbousertype.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtUserID.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Data Has Been Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Updated")
    ShowUser()
End Sub
```

Comment: Close the connection when you're done using it.  Put everything disposable into a Using - End Using block.

Comment: Could you explain me why i need to put them into Using please@Lars Tech

Comment: The End-Using part will automatically dispose the object.  You are leaving your connection open, which is bad management.